# React Native - Login Page : Fit all content on screen width (resize image)

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Hello here is a visual example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

This is the login screen for my app. I want to make sure that no matter what phone the user is doing everything fits on the screen without having to scroll. What I'm trying to do is make the image height dynamic so that it resizes based on the phone height.

I'm not sure how to approach this right now I have flex box set up and I have two children `view` inside of it. The bottom `view` is a fixed height so I set that equal to `220` and then for the top `view` I'm doing the phone height minus the fixed height.

The image and text are actually a slider that I'm using from here: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel

Again I'm not sure the best way to approach this, but I just want the image to resize depending on phone height. Here is my code:

```
const phoneHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const phoneWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

_renderItem({ item, index }) {
    return (
        <View style={{
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            marginBottom: 25,
            alignSelf: "center"
        }}>
            <View style={styles.ImageWrap}>
                <Image style={styles.imageStyle} source={item.image} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.TextWrap}>
                <Text style={styles.Title}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.Body}>{item.text}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.app}>
                    <View style={styles.appBody}>
                        <View style={styles.headerWrap}>
                            {/* HEADER CONTENT HERE */}
                        </View>
                        <Carousel
                            layout={"default"}
                            ref={ref => this.carousel = ref}
                            data={this.state.carouselItems}
                            sliderWidth={phoneWidth - 50}
                            itemWidth={phoneWidth - 50}
                            renderItem={this._renderItem}
                            onSnapToItem={index => this.setState({ activeIndex: index })} />
                        <View>
                            {/* Some Text Here HERE */}
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.footerWrap}>
                        {/* FIXED CONTENT HERE */}
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    loginBody: {
        display: 'flex',
        height: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    appBody: {
        height: phoneHeight - 220,
    },
    footerWrap: {
        height: 220,
    },
    ImageWrap: {
        height: phoneHeight / 4,        
    },
    imageStyle: {
        height: '100%',
        width: 'auto',
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to deal with this situation is `flex` and `Dimensions`.
It automatically sizes a component according to the screen size:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>  
  <View style={{flex: .5}}></View>
</View>
```

`flex: 1` corresponds to 100% of screen.

`flex: .5` corresponds to 50% of the parent's space, and so on.

It may help you:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';

const SCREENSIZE = Dimensions.get('screen');

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.appBody}>
          <View style={styles.innerBody}>
            <View style={styles.contentBox}>
              <Text>Header</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ ...styles.contentBox, flex: .4 }}>
              <Image
                style={styles.logo}
                resizeMethod="cover" # or contain
                source={{ uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1200px-React-icon.svg.png' }}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.contentBox}>
              <Text>Some text here</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.appFooter}>
        </View>
      </View >
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffa9aa',
  },
  appBody: {
    flex: .78,
  },
  innerBody: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    paddingVertical: SCREENSIZE.height * .08,
    paddingHorizontal: SCREENSIZE.width * .2,
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  appFooter: {
    flex: .22,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  contentBox: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: SCREENSIZE.width * .8,
    flex: .2,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: SCREENSIZE.width * .4,
    height: SCREENSIZE.width * .4,
  },
})
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. If i Know the height for the footer is always 220px. Can i use that instead of 0.2 ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but the footer will be always 220px in any phone instead of 22% of screen.

Comment: Okay I tried using your code exactly, everything fits great this way, but the image itself still gets cropped. It doesn't show the whole image. How do we make the height of the image fit the parent div height?

Comment: So, when the container dimensions mismatch image dimensions, you need to use `resizeMethod` props to resize it. The answer was updated.